# how to capture all quantified regex matches in Perl?

Tags: perl

If `regex` is a regular expression, I can capture two repetitions of it like this:

```
if (/(regex)(regex)/) {
    print $1;
    print $2;
}
```

But that is bad Perl, because one should use `{2}` quantifier, and bad general programming style, because it repeats code.  So I would like to do this:

```
if (/(regex){2}/) {
    print $1;
    print $2;
}
```

But this does not work, only the first match prints.

Is there a way to print both matches and not repeat code?

Comment: I think you may have confused people by abstracting your question too far from the real problem. If this were the actual problem I would just write `print $1 if /(regexregex)/`. So why can't you do that?

Comment: because regex is very long and I don't want to repeat it - each code should be in one place, and code repetition is bad

Comment: Then you need to use regex variables, like `my $re = qr/regex/ x 2` and then `if (/$re/) { ... }`

Comment: I think this comment is the best answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to put parentheses around the *entire* expression, including the quantifier, like `/((regex){2})/`. However, since the inner capture isn't needed it is best to use *non-capturing* parentheses `(?: ... )` so your code would look like

```
if ( /((?:regex){2})/ ) {
  print $1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? You can print the whole part that was matched:

```
if (/((regex){2})/) {
    print $1;
}
```

or you can try matching several times with `while` and `/g`. `\G` will ensure there are no characters between the matches.

```
while (/\G(regex)/g) {
    print $1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to match a regex multiple times in Perl and print all matches

This isn't what your program is doing. What your program is doing is whatever `regex` is, it must be twice in a row. The `{..}` are used to specify how many times you want something:

```
if ( $string =~ /a{2,3}/ ) {
     say "The string '$string' has two or three 'a' in a row";
}
```

However, what you *seem* to be asking is getting all times `$regex` occurs in a string. You can save the matches in an array like this:

```
my $string = "barfaafeebarbarfiifoo";
my @matches = ( $string =~ /f../g );
for my $match ( @matches ) { 
    say "$match";
}
```

This will print out:

```
faa
fee
fii
foo
```

If there are no matches to the regular expression `/f../`, then nothing would print out. I could test whether a match occurred by looking at the scalar value of `@matches` and seeing if it's greater than zero.

Note in this case I needed the `g` on the end of my regular expression.

Answer (score -2):

You could concatenate more than one regexp together this way if you do not care which one matched:

```
if ( $s =~ m!(regexp1|regexp2|regexp3)! ){
  print "found $1\n";
}
```

If you do care which one match I would do this:

```
foreach my $r ( 'regexp1','regexp2'){
    if ( $s =~ m!$r! ){
      print "$r matched: found $1 in $s\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how what you have written relates to the original question. You seem to be answering a different problem entirely